# Preloading assets in React-Native expo app never finishes

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, expo

I'm writing a simple app with React Native and Expo.

This app has ~10 small to medium sized images that are used in different places within the app.

From what I read, unless I cache these images, they will be required to be  *downloaded from expo each time*.

For this reason, I have noticed that they seem to load in really slowly when testing the app. Upon building and navigating through the app, I find that it takes a few seconds for my images to pop up even after the rest of the page has loaded.

I [followed the setup as seen in the starting template.](https://github.com/expo/new-project-template/blob/master/App.js)

Here is what my App.js looks like (I am using react-navigation so it varies from the sample file above):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
  }
  render() {
    _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
      return Promise.all([
        Asset.loadAsync([
          require("./assets/syria.png"),
          require("./assets/lebanon.png"),
          require("./assets/kenya.png"),
          require("./assets/indonesia.png"),
          require("./assets/somalia.png"),
          require("./assets/india.png"),
          require("./assets/america.png"),
          require("./assets/albania.png"),
          require("./assets/bosnia.png")
        ])
      ]);
    };
    _handleLoadingError = error => {
      Alert.alert(error);
    };

    _handleFinishLoading = () => {
      this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
    };

    if (this.state.isLoadingComplete == false) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AppContainer
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I have excluded my react-navigation code for the sake of brevity.

When I run this, my app gets stuck at `Downloading JavaScript bundle 100.00%`.

It seems that the _handleFinishLoading never runs. At least, that's the only reason I can see for it to never finish loading.

Given the small amount of images, I don't know how this could take more than a second. Instead it sits at the splash screen forever.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

I made a simple error. The async functions (_loadResourcesAsync, _handleFinishLoading, etc) need to be *outside* the render method. Moving them below my render method inside of the app class caused this to work as expected.